# Which system process do I block from the internet to prevent ads from showing up?

Tags: ads

Yes, this is similar to [my own previous question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19245/how-do-some-apps-get-past-ad-blocking) on the subject.
I'm being very specific here though - despite having wrapped ad blocking with hosts file and firewall, some apps (several more now) are able to merrily display banner ads even when they are explicitly blocked from connecting to the net. My firewall (Droidwall) works, because if I block a legitimate app it gets blocked.

How are they doing this?? Is there some Google made common system process that they access?

Comment: Have you tried AdAway?  It works very well on my phone for blocking ads.

Comment: See the linked question...already running all of that. This isn't a question on how to block ads, it's a question about getting rid of the rest!

Comment: Related: [How to Block/Filter Sites on Mobile Data Connection?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/149381/218526)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Such ads are not fetched from the internet, they are built into the app. Usually the ads would feature some other app from the same developer.

Comment: That seems likely..some of these are direct market links.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you still see those ads when you've blocked internet is because they're cached. If you erase the app data, then you won't see those ads, but all login information (if used) will also be deleted.

There isn't any specific process on the Android system that is responsible for fetching ads. The application itself fetches the ad. So unless you find a way to kill a thread on the app that fetches those ads, you won't be able to do anything.

Your best course of action is to:

1. Buy the paid version of the app. (Supports developers :-) )
2. Install some AdBlocker app. (Might require root.)
3. Bear with the ads.

Comment: Already done all that if you read my original question.